# Parameters are parsed weird using shell_exec with php

Tags: php, bash, sh

I have a PHP script, like this:

```
$command = "/home/user/dir/script.sh 'create' '" . $paramA . "' '" . $paramB . "'";

echo $command . PHP_EOL;
echo shell_exec($command);
```

(Script is actual, only obfuscated script and variable names. To make sure I wasn't going mad, I even tested the obfuscated version)
The contents of the .sh file are as follows:

```
if [[ $1 = "create" ]]
then
    Mode="Create"
elif [[ $1 = "delete" ]]
then
    Mode="Delete"
else
    echo "--- Invalid mode: $1; must be create or delete"
    exit 1
fi
```

Now, the output of the PHP script is as follows:

```
/home/user/dir/script.sh 'create' 'somevalue' 'someothervalue'
--- Invalid mode: create; must be create or delete
```

So... I am passing a command line parameter to this script, and the script thinks that the parameter isn't correct. But as you can see the script will dump the parameter value to stdout when it fails; where we can see that the value IS correct.

I **did also** test this script by copying the generated command line call to my own terminal, and this will execute.
Anyone got a clue ?

(as you can see from the response of the call, it can't have anything to do with permissions or anything, since the script *is* executing....)

Comment: I really hope those variables are not user data or you're playing with fire here.

Comment: Don't you need to use `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @tadman thanks for your worry, but no. This is a script that I run locally to make my life easier on my local machine.

Comment: It's worth calling [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) on these arguments in case you ever encounter filenames with spaces or other wacky characters in them. I've been given files called "Untitled (2).rtf" innumerable times.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your comment. Just so you know, even tho I run this locally, `$paramA` and `$paramB` are indeed fed through "escapeshellcmd()" for exactly the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen Good on you, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that Apache didn't execute the script with the same shell as me as a user.

Bash, not sh or csh.

Fixed with a shebang/hash-bang.